# Cannot resolve keyword 'XXX' into field

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the following class

```
class Advert(models.Model):
    ...
    title = models.TextField (
        verbose_name = 'Job Title',
    )
    advertiser = models.TextField (
        verbose_name = 'Advertiser',
    )
    first_advert = models.DateField (
        verbose_name = 'First Advertised',
        default = datetime.date.today
    )
    last_advert = models.DateField (
        verbose_name = 'Last Advertised',
        default = datetime.date.today
    )

    def posted_once(self):
        return (self.last_advert == self.first_advert)
    posted_once.short_description = 'Posted Once'
```

Within admin.py I'm trying to use posted_once for a filter

```
class AdvertAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['first_advert','last_advert',]
    ordering = ['-last_advert','first_advert']
    actions = [extract,]
    list_filter = ('posted_once',)
```

But I get the

> Cannot resolve keyword 'posted_once' into field

error.  Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t use a function as a list filter.

> **`list_filter`** should be a list or tuple of elements, where each element should be of one of the following types:
>
> - a field name, where the specified field should be either a **`BooleanField`**, **`CharField`**, **`DateField`**, **`DateTimeField`**, **`IntegerField`**, **`ForeignKey`** or **`ManyToManyField`**
> - a class inheriting from **`django.contrib.admin.SimpleListFilter`**, which you need to provide the **`title`** and **`parameter_name`** attributes to and override the **`lookups`** and **`queryset`** methods
> - a tuple, where the first element is a field name and the second element is a class inheriting from **`django.contrib.admin.FieldListFilter`**

So for your case, you’ll want to subclass either the SimpleListFilter or FieldListFilter [like the examples in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter).